# I'm unable to get my Ubuntu Desktop GUI Need my data in home folder

Tags: 14.04

I'm unable to get my Ubuntu Desktop GUI. I tried from recovery mode but able to accessing GRUB and file system mounting in root mode. How do I backup data?

Comment: If you just want to get to your files, rather than fix the broken GUI, you can use an Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to get access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here goes:  How to get your home folder backed up all safe and sound.  So, your home folder is always located at

```
/home/yourusername
```

What you are going to want to do is exactly this:

```
cp -R /home/yourusername /your/target/goes/here
```

The `-R` here tells the `cp` command to be recursive.  It will copy the folder itself, and the subfolders.  This will back up your whole home folder.